# Where can I find power manager program in Lenovo Thinkpad E530 edge?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-power-manager

I am using Linux for the first time and I am using Ubuntu 12.04

I am trying to find power manager on Thinkpad Lenovo, like what we have on Windows 7.

Comment: Take a look at [PowerManagement/ReducedPower](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a good official  power manager for Ubuntu like Windows but there is a unofficial power saving program for Asus EeePC Netbooks that works for other laptop well. Jupiter is an appindicator designed to improve laptops / netbooks battery life. It can be used to switch between maximum, high performance and power saving modes, change the screen resolution and orientation, enable or disable bluetooth, touchpad, WiFi (if available) and so on.

Install Jupiter using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Have a nice time.